# More detailed Facebook Page ads stats

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, ads

I've started as simple, 3-days long Facebook Pages Ads campaign. All the information, Facebook gives me is `Likes`, `Reach`, `Total Spent` and `Daily Budget`.

All values are summarized for entire campaign. Is there any way, I can see per-day stats of my campaign? I.e. how much did I spent each day according to daily budget, how close to reaching it I was etc. Summarized stats seems pretty useless to me, if we're talking about daily budgeting of ads.

Answer (score 1):

What I've learnt so far is that:

1. If you're logged as regular user (private profile), particular Facebook Page's owner you can see new "*Your Ads*" box in top-right corner of your [Home](https://www.facebook.com/), containing today and monthly stats for you ad campaign -- post  engagements and page likes. You can click any of these two values to get to the New Insights page, containing many stats and ad campaign metrics.
2. If you're logged in directly as your Facebook Page, you can see `Insights Summary` box in the very same place, but unfortunately only summarized.
3. If your campaign is over, you can click `View Campaign` button below to see a chart showing new page likes for each day of previously running campaign.
4. Clicking on `Insights > Check out the new Page Insights` and on many more links (number of likes or talks or `See Insights` button), you can access a detailed report, however `Overview` sections doesn't give per-day details and other tabs takes an awfully long time to load data or content.
5. If you go to [`Ads Manager`](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/), you can see detailed information about all your ads campaigns.

Seems this is all or most of. Please, re-edit or add another answer, if you find something else.